# New Facebook Chat list not working

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have the new Facebook layout with the chat listings on left hand side in a black column. It's giving me the following problems:

- Now the chat column minimises and I can't see the names or the green
  status dots.
- When I press the settings disc it won't operate.
- It looks terrible as the dark column flickers in and out.
- I can't see news feed notifications in the top of chat list any more.
- People don't see me when I'm online.
- Sometimes the words "chat options" flashes up somewhere but never on
  the settings disc, and then the actual options box hides in the left
  corner and I can only guess what I am pressing on.

It is most unsatisfactory. I tried to get back to old version but with no success. This one is actually faulty, because I know I have the chat turned on but it is not showing that way. It briefly did so, for about 10 seconds, and then went back to not showing.

What do I do to fix it? Will a system restore help?

Answer (score 2):

No, a system restore will probably not help you. It sounds like you've gotten [the newest Facebook design](https://www.facebook.com/help/411149058979649/) rolled out to you. It seems to still be buggy, which is why they still haven't rolled the changes out to everyone.

Facebook's Help section asks that users whose [chat bar keeps minimizing](https://www.facebook.com/help/130073717121856) to [file a bug report](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/?id=353602561329765).